# Use GtkStyleContext within GtkBuilder ui files

Tags: css, xml, gtk

How can I access a GtkWidget's StyleContext from within a GtkBuilder-.ui file? I know that, from Python for example, I could just use

```
SomeWidget.get_style_context().do_something()
```

How can I achieve this from a Builder file like this:

```
<object class="GtkSomeThing">
    <property name="Foo">Bar</property>
</object>
```

I would ideally like to simply add some CSS to the widgets using the Builder file. That just seems so much cleaner than coding it in Python, as I would be able to keep all the stuff needed for the UI definition in one place.

Comment: "stunningpotato" and "ptomato", lol, what are the odds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and it's documented [here](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget) under the "Gtk.Widget as Gtk.Buildable" heading. You can add

```
<style>
  <class name="some-css-class"/>
</style>
```

to your `<object>` element.